# how to get lambda current/executing version into environment variables using serverless template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I am using serverless template to create lambda function versions and Aliases, so I want to get latest/executing lambda version into environment variables.

actually I want to see the current/executing lambda version in environment variables.

I used "Version" key in environment variables, so how we can get latest lambda version into environment variables?

serverless.template:

{

```
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31"
"Resources": {
  "AspNetCoreFunction": {
    "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
    "Properties": {
      "Handler": "",
      "Runtime": "dotnetcore3.1",
      "CodeUri": "",
      "MemorySize": 256,
      "Environment": {
        "Variables": {
            "Version" : { "Ref" : "$?????" }
        }
      },
      "Timeout": 30,
      "Role": "<Role>",
      "Policies": null       
    }
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set this information in an environment variable. This is provided for free by the AWS Lambda Runtime through the `context` of the Lambda.

```
public async Task Handler(ILambdaContext context)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Function version: " + context.FunctionVersion);
}
```

Source: [AWS Lambda context object in C#](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-context.html)